# Is there any way to connect on AS400 system(iseries) with Visual Studio without using ODBC?

Tags: .net, connection, ibm-midrange

I am testing IBM.Data.DB2 and I download las t fix dll from IBM platform. I using this sentences:

myConnectionString = "Server=0.0.0.0:000;DATABASE=LIBRARYAS400;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD;Pooling=false;"

```
        Dim myConn As DB2Connection = New DB2Connection(myConnectionString)
        
        myConn.Open()
```

When i use this its waits a lot of time i dont know why i dont return anything.

Thats why i am asking about other way connecting to AS400 without using ODBC.

Comment: IBM.Data.Db2 isn't enough info to identify the driver being used.  I suspect you're using the wrong one.  Start [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=programming-net-provider)

Comment: HI Sr Charles Itry it other versions of IBM 10 and 11 and i stoped to try more. Thnks for info ^^ Emilio

Comment: There is no v10 or v11 version of the IBM i .NET driver.  There is a v10 or v11 of Db2 for LUW and it's included Db2 Connect.  But to use Db2 Connect with IBM i, you have to pay for a license.  Whereas the IBM i drivers included in [IBM Access Client Solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) are included with your license of IBM i OS.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for it. It uses the 6.x version of the iSeries client. It's not well documented and I don't use it anymore but it was heavily used when I wrote it. https://github.com/MikeWills/IBM-i-.NET-Interface. If anything, use it for examples of what worked.

Comment: Hi Sr Mike I will check it out. Thnks for your comment and work Emilio